# Are self-administered COVID tests valid for Singapore pre-entry purposes?

Tags: covid-19, singapore

Singapore's [Vaccinated Travel Lane](https://safetravel.ica.gov.sg/vtl/requirements-and-process) system requires a negative COVID-19 PCR or ART (aka antigen, rapid, RAT) test taken within 48 hours of departure.

There are now a number of self-administered COVID-19 tests including [BinaxNOW](https://www.abbott.com/corpnewsroom/diagnostics-testing/BinaxNOW-what-you-need-to-know.html), [Ellume](https://www.ellumecovidtest.com/) and [Qured](https://qured.com/), where you are mailed a kit and somebody guides you through testing yourself on a video chat, analyzes the results and sends you a certificate by mail.  ([Patrick "Ask the Pilot" Smith's blog on the topic here.](https://askthepilot.com/covid-testing-made-easy/))  These kits are often much cheaper and more convenient than trying to find a lab locally.

**Are these tests accepted for VTL pre-entry purposes in Singapore?**

*Update*: I originally asked this question when Singapore accepted only PCR tests, but they've changed the rules and now allow ART as well.  So open to new answers addressing that as well.

Comment: Ask yourself how easy it would be to abuse or cheat if it were allowed...

Comment: @J... Not all that easy? I've done antigen tests, and there's a control line: if you don't do the test properly, the line doesn't show up and the test result is invalid.

Comment: The control line doesn't say when the test was done nor who did it.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen These are video proctored tests, there's a lab representative watching you do it.  Sure, you could do sleight of hand tricks or whatever, but if you want to fake your result it would be easier to edit the PDF.

Comment: @lambshaanxy If it's video proctored with a lab representative, then it's not really self-administered, is it?

Comment: @J... You're still the one swabbing your own nose, no?

Comment: @lambshaanxyh Regardless, when you say a "self-administered" test you will cause people to think you are talking about those tests that people can buy on their own and use at home or anywhere else.  A supervised test in a lab is something entirely different, even though the specific step of sample collection is done by the person being tested.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, according to the official website you mentioned:

> Travellers must: 
> Take a COVID-19 **Polymerase Chain Reaction Test (“PCR test”)** within 48 hours before departure for Singapore **at** an internationally accredited or recognised laboratory, clinic, or medical facility, and test negative for COVID-19;

According to their websites, all the rapid tests you linked are **Antigen** tests, they are not PCR. In addition to that, the rules specifically mention that the test must be taken *at* a lab, clinic, or medical facility. These rapid home tests do not seem like they fit that criterion.

Comment: D'oh! The Qured site mentions a PCR test as well, but turns out it's only available at labs.  It *did* seem too good to be true...

Comment: Antigen tests are accepted for entering the USA.  https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/symptoms-testing/testing.html

Comment: @Dragonel but not self-administered ones, as the CDC explicitly says test results (so a test certificate) or proof of recovery

Comment: @AndreKR This is an internal affair of Germany, EU has nothing to do with that, the reuqirements are individual requirements of the countries.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza  The comment was in response to a since-removed line in the answer about antigen tests being almost never accepted, not specifically about self-tests.  However a lot of self-administered tests are sent away to a lab or video-checked by the provider who will give a lab report & certificate which is acceptable for travel.  First example found (no affiliation or endorsement) https://www.letsgetchecked.com/home-coronavirus-test/?imp=cpc&imp=cpc&gclid=Cj0KCQjww4OMBhCUARIsAILndv5j6CtIHNAX9prWIH_d6UJbHV17ofQwdkafd4G_M9jOjt8mXhLivnwaAna7EALw_wcB